# The "Try Stack Overflow for Business" dialog should have an explicit don't show again option

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Following on from [The new "try Stack Overflow for Business" popup won't go away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327580/the-new-try-stack-overflow-for-business-popup-wont-go-away), it's not obvious that clicking the `X` both dismisses the dialog and hides the button. Clicking elsewhere on the page simply closes the dialog *without* hiding the button.

Please consider adding a link, e.g. "Don't show again", for an obvious way to permanently hide the button.

[image: Screenshot of current dialog]

[image: Screenshot of proposed dialog]

Comment: Clicking the X on the top-right corner does exactly the same.

Comment: @CinCout Yes, I mentioned that in the question. But it's not very discoverable, e.g. I tried to dismiss it by clicking elsewhere on the page, which did hide the dialog but not the button. There was no reason to believe the X would do anything different, and it should not be necessary to search meta to find out.

Comment: @Bob, the `X` is not discoverable?

Comment: @StephenRauch The fact that the X *additionally hides the "new" button* is not discoverable, yes. I'm certainly not the only person (see: the linked question and its comments) who doesn't bother clicking an X when I can just click elsewhere on the page to hide the dialog, and the X is expected to do the same thing. But it doesn't. There's no incentive to try clicking X when it's clear the button remains after the dialog is gone.

Comment: As an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dId2k.gif Without having searched meta and found comments on the other question, I would not have even begun to guess that X could have done something different. I was actually going to look at writing a userscript to hide the button.